# virtual inheritance base constructor elimination

Tags: c++

```
struct A3 {
    int x;
    A3(int x_): x(x_) {cout << "A3: " << x_  << endl;}
};
struct B3: virtual public A3 {
    B3(int x_): A3(x_) {cout << "B3: " << x_  << endl;}
};
struct C3: virtual public A3 {
    C3(int x_): A3(x_) {cout << "C3: " << x_  << endl;}
};
struct D3: B3, C3 {

    D3(int x_): A3(x_), B3(x_), C3(x_) {cout << "D3: " << x_  << endl;}
};
```

for code above: output is A3, B3, C3, D3. It seems the compiler eliminated the calls to A3 in B3 and C3. 
How does the elimination work?
Does this mean we can only invoke A3's constructor from D3?

Answer (score 1):

> How does the elimination work?

It is an implementation detail, but that's normally accomplished by the compiler emitting two different constructors for a type. One constructor is used for the type when it's a base class, and the other is used when it's the most derived object type.

When a virtual base is present, the base class version of the c'tor doesn't contain a call to the virtual's c'tor. While the most derived object version of the c'tor *does* contain the call to the virtual base's c'tor.

Since the compiler knows in what context the type is used, it can select the appropriate c'tor to invoke.

> Does this mean we can only invoke A3's constructor from D3?

We can only invoke it from the most derived object type. If that type is `D3`, then that is the only c'tor that will invoke `A3`'s c'tor.

Answer (score 0):

Actually only one instance of A3 created in this case so yes implicitly we can only invoke A3's constructor from D3 but under the hood, the compiler can perform it in any convenient way.